# How can I add a custom tab to admin panel -> manage category in magento?

Tags: magento

I know that I can add form elements via install scripts using method addAttribute().
However, now I'd like to get a whole new tab next to General, Display Settings and such. I wonder what's the simpliest way to do it without overcomplicating.

Comment: You need new module or just change the core code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to do other parts of module.
You need overriding the:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs
```

On your config.xml you do:

```
    <blocks>           
         <adminhtml>  
            <rewrite> 
                 <catalog_category_tabs>YouModule_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs</catalog_category_tabs>  
            </rewrite>  
        </adminhtml>  
    </blocks>
```

You'll need overriding the _prepareLayout function.

And you'll write this code:

```
$this->addTab('idname', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Tab name'),
                'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('yourmodule/yourblock')->toHtml(),
        ));

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
```

Comment: Inside which file should I put the second code? Inside the block itself?

Comment: @PawelDuda the second code you should put on _prepareLayout() overrided function. Inside your block rewrited.

Comment: What should my block extend?

Comment: @Benubird Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs this one

Comment: No, I mean the block for the content - yourmodule/yourblock, what should that extend? Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template?

Comment: You can use any kind of block. Use ones who implement more usefull functions to ur case.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to rewriting the block would be to listen to the event `adminhtml_catalog_category_tabs` and then in your observer doing something like.

```
$tabs = $observer->getTabs();
$tabs->addTab('myextratab', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('My Extra Tab'),
    'content'   => 'Here is the contents for my extra tab'
));
```

This would help stop rewrite conflicts that could occur between different extensions.

Comment: `'content'   => 'Here is the contents for my extra tab'` how could I add a block here? I'd written this code `'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_tab_form')` but the page stops loading...

Comment: @MohammadFaisal `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/adminhtml_module_tab_form')->toHtml()`

Comment: sorry to mention but I've used `->toHtml()` too

Comment: actually I'm working on a module where I do need to have a featured product per category... can you suggest me a good alternative?